# Installing Ubuntu on a Windows 8 (pre-installed) laptop

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

I bought a new Sony Vaio laptop with windows 8 pre-installed. I want to install ubuntu and dual boot between windows 8 and ubuntu. I've done this many times on Windows 7 machines but I have no idea how to deal with this new UEFI stuff. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/44179

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit version and be sure to boot it in UEFI mode not BIOS/legacy/AHCI mode.

Prolly after installing you will have to use boot repair on a live session since it will keep booting windows 8.